# ...followed by (Function)

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> ...The construction with "of" seems to be the most common,
>   ***followed*** by the one with no preposition, and then by the ones with "in" and "at" .
>
> The funeral is at 3.00, ***followed*** by a reception at X bar.

What is the function of "followed by" in those sentences above? Is it a participle? DOes it act as an adverb or noun?

Does it modify the whole main clause? or just the subject of the main clause, "the construction" and "the funeral" ?

Answer (score 3):

It's a [reduced relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause): *The funeral is at 3.00,* (which will be) *followed by a reception at X bar.*

Comment: Thank you. Can I rewrite them like this as well: a- "The funeral is at 3.00, ***which is followed*** by a reception at X bar." b- ".The construction with "of" seems to be the most common, ***which is followed*** by the one with no preposition, and then by the ones with "in" and "at" .

Comment: + In these sentences, do reduced relative clauses modify the whole main clause? or just the subject of the main clause, ***"the construction"*** and ***"the funeral"*** ?

Comment: It depends—as is the case with relative clauses, sometimes they modify only the subject, sometimes the whole clause. But I strongly advise you against rewriting—English is the language of contractions and ellipses, the shorter, the better.

Comment: If this is indeed a 'reduced' relative clause, which I would dispute, it doesn't modify anything. Non-defining relative clauses, reduced or otherwise, are not modifiers; rather, they have a semantic 'anchor' that they refer to. In this case the anchor would be "the funeral is at 3.00". I would call the clause a supplementary adjunct, a loosely attached expression presenting supplementary, non-integrated content.

Comment: @BillJ I agree that maybe _modify_ might not be the best term here. But English linguistics terminolgy is so complicated and vague, so... On the other hand, it is indeed a reduced relative clause, imo, since we cannot drop the main part\anchor. At least, my example: _"The funeral is at 3.00, which will be followed by a reception at X bar"_ contains an unequivocal relative, refering to the whole of the previous clause.

Comment: _Clauses beginning with question words (e.g. who, which, where) are often used to **modify** nouns and some pronouns - to identify people and things, or to give more information about them. Clauses used_ [sic] _like this are called 'relative clauses'._ (M.Swan _Practical English Usage_)

Comment: @MichaelLogin I haven't read Swan, but I assume he's talking about defining relative clauses, the kind without commas, and they are indeed modifiers.